# Include remote php to store variable into db

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Daer friends, I have a php page for telegram webhook, and i would store data into mysql db calling an exeternal php page like so:

```
include 'http://www.xxxx.it/send_prenota.php?chat_id='.$chat_id;
```

Why dont work? If I call directly the page, work fine!

Comment: Did you see the manual's section on using URLs instead of local files? http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php. `If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a local pathname.` and `This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script.`.

Comment: What is your `allow_url_include` ini setting?

Comment: the php webhook is stored into heroku app! I couldnt manage php.init

Comment: create a php page with `<? phpinfo(); ?>` to check the setting of your php.ini

Comment: allow_url_include is setting to off :(